# How to write a R function to check whether a variable is a non-numeric variable and switch it to numeric

Tags: r

I want to wirte a R function to check whether a variable is a non-numeric variable and switch it to numeric.

For example, there are five variables: age, sex, BMI, blood_pressure, blood_glucose. I need to write following code for five times. Is there a quick way to process these variables in batches?

```
typeof(dt$age)

dt$age <- as.numeric(dt$age)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `across` inside `mutate` to apply a function to all variables:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df,across(.fns = as.numeric))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a way to change part of the variables not all variables? Because several varibales were recorded as character variable completely such as sex (recorded as men and women), I want to check and change variables according to my needs.

Comment: Inside `across` there is parameter called `.cols` where yo can define the variables

Comment: I searched related information on `across` function. It is a brilliant function, I learned a lot. Thank you very much.